# Google Compute Engine OpenERP

Tags: python, debian, odoo, google-compute-engine

I already install OpenERP and PostgreSQL in google compute engine.
Using debian 7. when i check with ifconfig as root user. I just got 2 ip addres.
127.0.0.1 and my internal ip address. My external IP/IP Public can't detected by debian 7.
I use ephemeral ip address for my external IP.

I allready try run OpenERP service using 127.0.0.1:8069 and my internal IP 10.240.226.xxx.
I can't access it from my external IP 8.34.xxx.xx:8069.

Please give me advice to fix these problem? and where i can contact or find Google "Help & Support" or submit "ticket support", beside using stackoverflow and google group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

External IP addresses are NAT'ed and are not visible to the host OS. It sounds like you already know your address, but for completeness, you can find it in the Cloud Console, or using gcutil:

```
gcutil getinstance YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME
```

In your case, it sounds like you likely need create a firewall rule to open port 8069. By default, all ports except for 22 (SSH) are blocked. You can create firewall rules in Cloud Console --> Compute Engine --> Networks --> default --> Firewalls --> Create New. Or using gcutil:

```
gcutil addfirewall --allowed=tcp:8069 "allow-openerp"
```

Be careful, this will allow external access to port 8069 for **all** VMs in your project. See the [firewall documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, i follow your advice and success.

Answer (score 0):

you could limit access to your OpenERP instance by specifying --allowed_ip_sources="x.x.x.x" the IP or the CIDR range from where you expect the application to be accessed.

Additionally limit access of 8060 port only to your OpenERP instance, by tagging the instance as say ERP and apply --target_tags="ERP" to limit traffic from your source IP range to hit only the specific ERP instance.